# if a tutorial is about a video game and not a computer is it still arcade or is it superuser?

Tags: support, minecraft, stack-exchange

I'm thinking of looking for a good tutorial on armegetron advanced or minecraft. Is that superuser or arcade? Could it be asked in either one? I know that tech tutorials are usually superuser. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't ask for game tutorials, either here or on SuperUser, It's off-topic on both sites. On SuperUser, anything videogame-related is off-topic. You can see what is and isn't on topic there by viewing the [SuperUser About](https://superuser.com/tour) page.

As for Arqade, tutorial requests generally fall into a few of our off-topic reasons (emphasis mine):

> - Requests for game identification or **recommendations**
> - Questions that are **primarily opinion-based**, speculative, or gossipy
> - Questions with **too many possible answers** or that would require an extremely long answer

In other words, if you ask: *"What is the best tutorial for Minecraft?"*, you're asking for a **recommendation**, which is someone's **opinion** on what the 'best' tutorial is, and because everyone's opinion is different, your question will attract **too many possible answers**.

You can read more into what is and isn't on topic here by viewing the [Arqade About](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) page.

---

But it isn't all doom and gloom! Instead of asking for a *tutorial*, you should ask for detail on a **specific problem that you're facing**. Take Minecraft for example. You could ask questions like:

> - [When do mobs despawn in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/when-do-mobs-despawn-in-minecraft), OR
> - [How can I find my World's Strongholds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30340/how-can-i-find-my-worlds-strongholds), OR
> - [How do I find slimes in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14783/how-do-i-find-slimes-in-minecraft), OR
> - [Do shorn sheep regrow their wool?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/do-shorn-sheep-regrow-their-wool)

Of course, try to figure out the problem yourself first, and show this research in your question. This shows potential answerers that you've at least tried to solve your problem first, and will stop them wasting yours and their time by suggesting things you've already tried. I'd suggest having a look at the [How to Ask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for a bit more of an overview.

Side note: It's perfectly fine for someone to **answer** a question with a linked tutorial for reference, so long as they **summarise the content of the tutorial** to prevent the link from disappearing (going stale/link rot)